# StopService does not call onDestroy immediately

Tags: android, android-service

I am using the following statement to stop a download service (that extends IntentService) running in the background:

```
    context.stopService(intent);
```

But this statement is not calling the onDestory() method of service immediately, It is taking sometime to call onDestroy() method of service.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("JSLog", "on destroy called");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

What should I do that after hitting the stopService() statement, it should immediately called onDestroy() method of the service.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554465/how-to-stop-service-immediately

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I followed the tutorial at [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample), which uses a `ServiceConnection`. In the example code, they call `unbindService()` but never `stopService()`. So I added a call to `stopService()` to stop it, but still `onDestroy()` never got called.

From the documentation of [Context.stopService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService(android.content.Intent)):

> Note that if a stopped service still has ServiceConnection objects bound to it with the BIND_AUTO_CREATE set, it will not be destroyed until all of these bindings are removed.

I interpreted this as it's okay to call `stopService()` or `stopSelf()` first, and then `unbindService()` afterwards (I'm using `BIND_AUTO_CREATE`) - and that the service would be stopped/destroyed upon calling `unbindService()`.

But it turns out that this isn't the case. When I moved things around so that I'm calling `unbindService()` first and `stopService()` after that, my `onDestroy()` gets called immediately.

Comment: This was very helpful. In my case i did not call unbindService and that caused onDestroy was never called.

Answer (score 2):

the intentService has new Thread,when u stop the service the new thread won't stop right now,if u want stop the thread right now ,i will extends service and new Thread in the service,when u need stop the service just need interrupt the thread.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour, a Service won't immediately be destroyed once stopped just like an Activity might not be immediately destroyed once finished (unless you finish inside onCreate).

Comment: Then how should I stop it ? Is there any way ?